# AWS Athena Data Sources API

Tags: amazon-athena

I have checked AWS documentation for Athena Data Sources https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-sources-managing.html and I have also checked AWS CLI for all available commands, but I was not able to find any API that would allow me to set AWS Athena Data Source via programmatic way.

I was successful in automating deployment of SAR app for connectors, but I have been unable to automate configuration of Athena Data Source at all.

Is there any public API for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

After more searching, it's named 'data-catalog', so appropriate action is to call `create-data-catalog` with proper attributes